# Ext JS header placement order

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to have a button in panel header. This is a part of my code:

```
var dashboardPanel4 = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        margin: '0 0 50 0',
        glyph: 'xf2a0@FontAwesome',
        layout: {
            type: 'table',
            columns: 4,
            tableAttrs: {
                width: '100%'
            }
        },
        defaults: {
            // applied to each contained panel
            bodyStyle: 'padding:10px',
            border: 0
        },


        title: '<span class="requests" id="requests"><a href="#" style="">Requests</a></span>',

        header: {
            xtype: 'header',
            titlePosition: 0,
            defaults: {
                margin: '0 10px'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: "Test Button",
                    tooltip: "Add something",
                    iconCls: 'add',
                    handler: Ext.bind(function() {
                    }, this)
                }
            ]
        },
```

But the problem is that fontawesome icon aligns into right position. Is there a way how to set FA icon before this title 'Requests'.

At the moment it is like this:

[image]

It should be: FA icon, Request and Button on right side.

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: For this project I use Ext JS 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have in the header the things align like this:
`<icon> <title> <other things>`

I would do it with the config [`titlePosition: 1,`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Header-cfg-titlePosition) which sets the title as a second item. Next thing what is needed is to just add the icon not by using `glyph` config but rather add it as own item in the header config.

So you would get something like this:

```
header: {
    xtype: 'header',
    titlePosition: 1,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'image',
        glyph: 'xf2a0@FontAwesome',
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: "Test Button",
        tooltip: "Add something",
        iconCls: 'add',
        handler: Ext.bind(function () {}, this)
    }]
},
```

Here is fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2h99 (the font awesome icons are not loaded in the example) but it should work in your own code.

*Btw there might be more solutions to this problem.*

Comment: It works. However the icon is very very small. Any way to enlarge it?

Comment: Hmmm, you can try to set `height` & `width` of the `image` object http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Img

Comment: You could try to set `style: 'font-size:48px;'` that's the way to enlarge the icons when they are on their own. But I think the size might be limited by the header size :|